# Swift: Type does not conform to protocol 'ArrayLiteralConvertible'

Tags: swift

Keep getting an error in my playground saying that Set does not conform to protocol 'ArrayLiteralConvertible'

---

```
struct Set<T: Hashable> : ArrayLiteralConvertible {
    typealias Element = T
    private var contents: [Element: Bool]

    init() {
        self.contents = [Element: Bool]()
    }

    // easier initialization
    init<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(_ sequence: S) {
        self.contents = [Element: Bool]()
        Swift.map(sequence) { self.contents[$0] = true }
    }

    // allow Set creation through simple assignment using ArrayLiteralConvertible protocol
    internal static func convertFromArrayLiteral(elements: Element...) -> Set {
        return Set(elements)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayLiteralConvertible` requires you to implement an initializer of type `init(arrayLiteral: Element...)`.  Something like this would re-use your initializer that takes a sequence:

```
init(arrayLiteral: Element...) {
    self = Set(arrayLiteral)
}
```

If you’re doing this in a playground, hit opt-cmd-enter to see more details in the assistant editor than you get just from the error message in the source.  It shows the details of all the protocol requirements you aren’t meeting.

By the way, if you declared contents like this:

```
private var contents: [Element: Bool] = [:]
```

you wouldn’t need to initialize it in each of your initializers.

Comment: Haven't seen that keyboard short cut before, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayLiteralConvertible` protocol needs an initializer `init(arrayLiteral elements: Element...)` in the class

```
 init(arrayLiteral elements: Element...) {
     self = Set(elements)
 }
```

You don't need to implement the `convertFromArrayLiteral` function anymore. It was in the old version of swift. It was deprecated in iOS 8.1 API. You just need the initializer above.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS81APIDiffs/modules/Swift.html

http://swiftdoc.org/protocol/ArrayLiteralConvertible/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, you got me on the right track. I found a gist on the github with some ArrayLiteralConvertible changes in syntax. It went to this tune:

```
init(arrayLiteral elements: T...) {
        self.init(elements)
}
```

This seems to work.